# How to get a maximum value of two columns from a single table?

Tags: mysql

Assume as I have an table named as Item, and Here I am going to give the sample table values and my expected out put

```
Item
------
Sl.No   Itemname    Rate    Date

1        A      200             15/01/2013
2        B      500             24/05/2013
3        C      600             12/06/2013
4        A      400             17/07/2013
5        A      550             18/08/2013
6        B      150             19/09/2013
7        C      140             20/10/2013


Expected Output:

Sl.No   Itemname    Rate    Date

1         A         550        18/08/2013
2         B         150        19/09/2013
3         C         140        20/10/2013
```

What is query can be written to get this output??

I have just tried out this query,

```
select * from postagitem group by categoryname where date = 
  (SELECT MAX(date) FROM postagitem);
```

But its not working, its really appreciable if anyone help me friends,

Thanks in Advance!

---

Thanks to all for your valuable response friends,

but still am not getting my correct output friends,

Actually i want to display the all the values with the condition of maximum date. For your clearance let me give my original table and values

Table Name: Price

City        Gold_Rate   Silver_Rate Date

Mumbai      3000        60      13-07-2014
Delhi       4000        50      14-04-2014
Bangalore   1400        40      16-06-2014
Mumbai      1500        58      18-09-2014
Mumbai      2500        54      19-08-2014
Delhi       1800        60      01-10-2014
Bangalore   1700        44      02-11-2014

Now the expected output will be

City        Gold_Rate   Silver_Rate Date

Mumbai      1500        58      18-09-2014 --> (the record of the maximum/recent date)
Delhi       1800        60      01-10-2014 --> (the record of the maximum/recent date)
Bangalore   1400        40      16-06-2014 --> (the record of the maximum/recent date)

How to write the query friends,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why value of B & C are not max ?

Comment: Why do you want S1.No to be 1 in the results for A rather than 5?

Comment: @IleshPatel he is taking latest by date

Comment: you want max value or the max sn for that value

Comment: (Not that it's especially relevant to this problem but) I'm SQL. i do not know what an '15/01/2013' is. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query does the trick that you want:

```
SELECT B.MINSLNO, B.ITEMNAME, A.RATE, B.MAXDATE FROM
MY_TABLE A,
(
   SELECT MIN(SLNO) MINSLNO, ITEMNAME, MAX(DATEE) MAXDATE FROM MY_TABLE
   GROUP BY ITEMNAME
) B
WHERE A.DATEE = B.MAXDATE
```

---

**OUTPUT:**  (Gives the itemnames, min slno of the item, max date of the item, rate as on maxdate for the item)

```
 Minslno    |itemname| rate  | maxdate
    1       |A       |550    |  18-AUG-2013
    2       |B       |  150  |  19-SEP-2013
    3       |C       |140    |  20-OCT-2013
```

[JS Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6d0ee/1)

Answer (score 1):

IF BY MAX DATE

```
SELECT * FROM test t 
where date=(select max(date) from test t1 where t.itemname=t1.itemname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this query will give you expected result:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` t1
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM `table` t2
       WHERE t1.Itemname = t2.Itemname AND
             t1.Date < t2.date) = 0
```

Same query, but this one might be simpler to understand:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) FROM `table` t2 WHERE t1.Itemname = t2.Itemname AND t1.Date < t2.date) AS `LaterRecords`
FROM `table` t1
HAVING `LaterRecords` = 0
```

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian for each row I select number of rows which has same Itemname and later date. And if there is no such rows (count == 0) i display this row. There is bug, if same item has multiple records per max date, but looks like other answers does not fix this problem as well

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian added another query which might help to understand firs one

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this

```
SELECT T1.M_SINO AS SL_NO,T.ITEMNAME,T.RATE,T.DATE 
FROM Test T INNER JOIN
     (SELECT Itemname,Max(date)MyDat ,Min(SL_NO) As M_SINO 
      FROM Test 
      GROUP BY Itemname) T1 ON
      T.Date = T1.MyDat AND
      T.Itemname = T1.Itemname
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a04f43/5)**

*Output:*

---

```
Sl.No   Itemname    Rate       Date

1         A         550        18/08/2013
2         B         150        19/09/2013
3         C         140        20/10/2013
```

Comment: Dude, this s query is not working for me..I need the query to display the record which is relevant to the max(date)..